# Bootstrap rows overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a page that has two sections that stack on top of each other using rows. Each section is supposed to be the height of the browser window but for some reason the second row overlaps most of the first except for the header.

Here is a link to my code:
http://www.bootply.com/WwcepyZC01

Comment: Please copy the relevant portions of your code to your question, because links can break.

Comment: I would not recommend doing any custom styling to the row or column classes. That can mess up things very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this using `height: 100vh`, and remove the `position: absolute`. I've also restructured your HTML a bit so that `.layer2` is **not** a child of `.layer1`.

```css
.layer1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(<%=asset_path "home_bg.jpg"%>);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: purple;
}
.title-wide h1 {
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 10vmax;
}
.home-caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  top: 30%;
}
.title-wide h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 4vmax;
}
.col-md-7 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 10vw;
}
.btn-default {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
.title-wide {
  left: 90%;
  right: 90%;
}
.btn-xlarge {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 200px;
  border: 2px solid none;
  text-align: center center;
  height: 3em;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 10em;
}
.layer2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer1 row-fluid">
  <div class="title-wide text-center">
    <h1>My Name</h1>
    <div class="home-caption text-center">
      <h2>I am a person working for a nameless corporation</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <hr>
        <div class="offset4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="layer2 row-fluid">

</div>


<div id="push"></div>
```